# Is there any use in using "::member" to reference the global namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

In C++, members of a namespace `myNamespace` can be referenced as `myNamespace::member`.

However, there apparently exists a syntax similar to the one above for referencing the global namespace - simply `::member`. Consider:

```
int foo() {
    return 4;
}

::foo(); // What is the difference between
foo();   // these two lines?
```

In short, is there a functional difference between using `foo();` and `::foo();` in this scenario, or are they completely identical?

Comment: and when foo() exists in namespace `myNamespace` this allows you to pick the global one

Comment: Is is a good idea to always use `::` prefix when referring to symbols in global namespace. Note that this effects namespace names as well, e.g. writing `::myNamespace::member` instead of `myNamespace::member` or `::std::something` instead of just `std::something`. This could save a lot of efforts when dealing with large code bases with multiple name collisions.

Comment: Thank you, @VTT, can you explain why this is the case?

Comment: Writing `::std` is not really needed, based on the rule that any programmer stupid enough to add a nested `std` namespace somewhere else will immediately get fired. So never happens.

Comment: @BoPersson Never say never. [Nested `std` namespaces exist in boost](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/master/include/boost/hana/ext/std/array.hpp#L70) for example. I've also seen nested `std` namespace used for backporting and `std` used for something other than a namespace name.

Answer (score 1):

Example code :

```
#include <iostream>

void foo() {
  std::cout << 1;
}

namespace my_ns
{
  void foo() {
    std::cout << 2;
  }

  void goo1() {
    ::foo();
  }
  void goo2() {
    foo();
  }
}

int main(int c, char** args) {
  my_ns::goo1();
  my_ns::goo2();
  return 0;
}
```